# How do I write a this constructor to establish or or the other possibility?

Tags: java

I have an "Abstract" class called "GuitarPlayer". I then declare two subclasses of "GuitarPlayer":

1. AcousticGuitarPlayer
2. ElectricGuitarPlayer

I then have a class called "Band". Within "Band" class the guitar player can either be an "Acoustic Guitar Player" or an "Electri cGuitar Player". How do I set the class constructor to establish this? I thought about using "instanceof()" method, but am uncertain how to establish the logic that if a guitar player is not an "Electric Guitar Player" then it is an "Acoustic Guitar Player".

Comment: Could you show your code first?

Comment: Why even need or use instanceof? Just assume that he's a GuitarPlayer and go with it.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here? Is it that you need to access methods of `ElectricGuitarPlayer` or `AcousticGuitarPlayer` within `Band` that the other class doesn't have or inherit from `GuitarPlayer`?

Comment: You guys should read @mbs answer, you might learn learn a thing or two. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Band class needs a member of the type GuitarPlayer that both classes inherit from.

```
public class Band {

    private GuitarPlayer gPlayer;

    public Band(GuitarPlayer gPlayer) {
        this.gPlayer = gPlayer;
    }

}
```

Because both `ElectricGuitarPlayer` and `AcousticGuitarPlayer` inherit from `GuitarPlayer` you can do this:

```
Band metalBand = new Band(new ElectricGuitarPlayer());
Band folkBand = new Band(new AcousticGuitarPlayer());
```

And as an example of the kinds of ways you can interact with the objects:

```
// assume GuitarPlayer has a play() method
metalBand.getGuitarPlayer().play();
folkBand.getGuitarPlayer().play();

// assume ElectricGuitarPlayer only has a whammy() method
ElectricGuitarPlayer electric = (ElectricGuitarPlayer) metalBand.getGuitarPlayer();
electric.whammy();
// assume AcousticGuitarPlayer only has a strum() method
AcousticGuitarPlayer acoustic = (AcousticGuitarPlayer) folkBand.getGuitarPlayer();
acoustic.strum();
```

you should use a `try...catch` block that catches a `ClassCastException` when you try to do any casting in case things don't fit.

To be more helpful we'll need more details of what your exact issue is.

Comment: Yes. Treating all subclasses as `GuitarPlayer` is the core of OOP. See  [liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: Thank you @mbs for your time and the explanation. This all makes sense and am now able to implement what I had been trying to do for hours. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one constructor this should be enough:

```
public Band(GuitarPlayer guitarPlayer) {
    this.guitarPlayer = guitarPlayer;
}
```

or you can have a constructor for each type:

```
    public Band(AcousticGuitarPlayer acousticGuitarPlayer) {
    guitarPlayer = acousticGuitarPlayer;
}

public Band(ElectricGuitarPlayer electricGuitarPlayer) {
    guitarPlayer = electricGuitarPlayer;
}
```